# Laravel 5.3: Use a array field from a controller in the view for trans()

Tags: arrays, laravel, translation, laravel-5.3

I have a form, which is sending the data of the form to a controller using POST.

The controller returns the array of data using this line:

```
return view('pages.result', compact('request'))
```

The view displays me the correct array with all data, when I use this code in the view:

```
<?php $input = $request->all(); echo "<pre>"; print_r($input); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Now I want to use the field "name" of the array in a translation. The following line of code...

```
{{ trans('auth.resultMessage', ['name' => '<?php echo $result['name']; ?>']) }}
```

...displays this:

```
{{ trans('auth.resultMessage', ['name' => 'Max']) }}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't use the translation text. It should look like this:

```
Everything worked fine, Max.
```

I've also tried the following solution, but this ends with the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'`:

```
{{ trans('auth.resultMessage', ['name' => '{{ Request::input("name") }}']) }}
```

How can I use the array field in the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you should just supply the variable without trying to echoing it. Like this, for instance:

```
{{ trans('auth.resultMessage', ['name' => $request->name]) }}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood the question correctly. Sometimes, I believe, I think a bit to difficult. Your solution worked like a charm! Thank you very much!